# Framerate Measurement Utility

Tags: c#, performance, object-oriented, .net

As part of a project I'm working on, I need to measure FPS. In the past, I would do this within the actual project itself, but recently I've been trying to implement more abstract (and reusable) manners of doing such simple things.

So, I built an `FpsCounter` class that handles all this for me!

```
/// <summary>
/// A utilitarian class for calculating FPS.
/// </summary>
public class FpsCounter
{
    private List<DateTime> _Frames;
    private TimeSpan _ExpirationTime = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the average FPS over the last hour (60 minutes, 3600 seconds).
    /// </summary>
    public int LastHour
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            int n = 0;
            TimeSpan difference = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);

            for (int i = _Frames.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                if (now - _Frames[i] < difference)
                    n++;
                else
                    break;

            if (n > 1)
                return (int)(n / (_Frames[_Frames.Count - 1] - _Frames[0]).TotalSeconds);

            return 0;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the average FPS over the last minute (60 seconds).
    /// </summary>
    public int LastMinute
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            int n = 0;
            TimeSpan difference = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);

            for (int i = _Frames.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                if (now - _Frames[i] < difference)
                    n++;
                else
                    break;

            if (n > 1)
                return (int)(n / (_Frames[_Frames.Count - 1] - _Frames[_Frames.Count - n]).TotalSeconds);

            return 0;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the average FPS over the last second.
    /// </summary>
    public int LastSecond
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            int n = 0;
            TimeSpan difference = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);

            for (int i = _Frames.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                if (now - _Frames[i] < difference)
                    n++;
                else
                    break;

            return n;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the FPS between the last two frames.
    /// </summary>
    public int Immediate
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Frames.Count > 2)
                return 1000 / (int)(_Frames[_Frames.Count - 1] - _Frames[_Frames.Count - 2]).TotalMilliseconds;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the amount of time after which a frame would expire.
    /// </summary>
    public TimeSpan ExpirationTime
    {
        get
        {
            return _ExpirationTime;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of the <see cref="FpsCounter"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public FpsCounter()
    {
        _Frames = new List<DateTime>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of the <see cref="FpsCounter"/> with the specified <see cref="ExpirationTime"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="expirationTime">The <code>TimeSpan</code> that represents the <see cref="ExpirationTime"/> for this <see cref="FpsCounter"/> instance.</param>
    public FpsCounter(TimeSpan expirationTime)
        : this()
    {
        _ExpirationTime = expirationTime;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates that a frame has passed. This should be called on each instance of a frame being drawn or updated (but not both).
    /// </summary>
    public void AddFrame()
    {
        _Frames.Add(DateTime.Now);

        for (int i = 0; i < _Frames.Count; i++)
            if (_Frames[i] - DateTime.Now > _ExpirationTime)
                _Frames.RemoveAt(i);
            else
                break;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the average FPS over the last specified of seconds.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="previousSeconds">The number of seconds previous to now that should be measured.</param>
    /// <returns>The FPS value for the last number of specified seconds.</returns>
    public int LastSeconds(int previousSeconds)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        int n = 0;
        TimeSpan difference = new TimeSpan(0, 0, previousSeconds);

        for (int i = _Frames.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (now - _Frames[i] < difference)
                n++;
            else
                break;

        if (n > 1)
            return (int)(n / (_Frames[_Frames.Count - 1] - _Frames[_Frames.Count - n]).TotalSeconds);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Essentially, I'm not convinced that the `LastHour`, `LastMinute`, `LastSecond` and `Immediate` properties should be, erm, well, properties. I'm curious, especially, on feedback regarding that.

Otherwise, pick away. All **constructive** comments/critique welcome.

Comment: Internal timings should always prefer DateTime.UtcNow over DateTime.Now.  Or consider a Stopwatch.

Comment: @RickDavin A `Stopwatch` would be significantly more difficult. Not impossible, but more difficult.

Comment: Ok then.  DateTime.UtcNow is much faster than DateTime.Now (which must call UtcNow first anyway) and also is not prone to time changes if you run this app during a time transition.  Most importantly, for consistency Microsost recommends that any comparison of two DateTime instances should be done where their Kind matches.

Comment: @RickDavin Aha, you should add that as an answer for the +1. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any internal timings, you really should prefer `DateTime.UtcNow` over `DateTime.Now` for 2 key reasons: (1) `UtcNow` is much faster than `Now`, which is expected since one of the first thing `Now` does is call `UtcNow`. and (2) `UtcNow` is less fragile to breaking if you are measuring any timings during a DST transition.  I know some who will say "But I never will run this during a transition" but still a best practice is a best practice any time of day.

The most important thing when comparing `DateTime` instances is that their `Kind` should match, or more to the point that the objects represent times in the same time zone.  Easy enough to achieve if you stick with `UtcNow`.

Also note that equality and other comparisons are done with `Ticks` and ignores `Kind` (hence their caution).  Don't know how big your lists will be but you might consider just storing the ticks instead of the full `DateTime`, e.g. `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks`.

[MSDN DateTime Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx) See Remarks:

> To determine the relationship of t1 to t2, the Compare method compares
>   the Ticks property of t1 and t2 but ignores their Kind property.
>   Before comparing DateTime objects, ensure that the objects represent
>   times in the same time zone.

As well as Microsoft's Online Reference to:

[DateTime.UtcNow](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,b0d5e4c9a8d4ddac)

[DateTime.Now](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,1cd5dd408a32124f)

Answer (score 2):

Too much for a property

> ```
> /// <summary>
> /// Gets the average FPS over the last hour (60 minutes, 3600 seconds).
> /// </summary>
> public int LastHour
> {
>     get
>     {
>         DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
>         int n = 0;
>         TimeSpan difference = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
>
>         for (int i = _Frames.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
>             if (now - _Frames[i] < difference)
>                 n++;
>             else
>                 break;
>
>         if (n > 1)
>             return (int)(n / (_Frames[_Frames.Count - 1] - _Frames[0]).TotalSeconds);
>
>         return 0;
>     }
> }
> ```

This should be a int Method.

You shouldn't make a property dynamic, that is not what a property is.  The reason that you can put logic inside getters and setters is so that you can set limits not so that you can perform complex operations to determine what the property is.