# XNA KeyboardStateManager

Tags: c#, .net, xna

This class allows for easy management of the `KeyboardState` of an XNA game.

It provides a simple, easy-to-use API for interacting with the Keyboard and getting key-presses, via a few (trivial) events.

As far as I can test, it works as intended.

GitHub Link (for future reference) as of this version: [`KeyboardStateManager`](https://github.com/EBrown8534/Framework/blob/079326ba905f19cb1c56dce888c4a5dc742c7399/Evbpc.Framework.Xna/Utilities/KeyboardStateManager.cs).

```
/// <summary>
/// This provides an easy-to-use class to interact with the Keyboard in an XNA game.
/// </summary>
public class KeyboardStateManager
{
    private KeyboardState _kPrev;
    private KeyboardState _kNow;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <code>KeyboardState</code> from the previous update.
    /// </summary>
    public KeyboardState KeyStatePrevious { get { return _kPrev; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <code>KeyboardState</code> from the current update.
    /// </summary>
    public KeyboardState KeyStateNow { get { return _kNow; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the internal <code>KeyboardState</code> and fires relevant events.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kState">The new <code>KeyboardState</code>.</param>
    public void Update(KeyboardState kState)
    {
        _kPrev = _kNow;
        _kNow = kState;

        List<Evbpc.Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys> keysDownNow = GetPressedKeys(_kNow);
        List<Evbpc.Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys> keysDownPrev = GetPressedKeys(_kPrev);
        List<Evbpc.Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys> keysPressed = GetPressedKeys();

        foreach (Evbpc.Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys keyDownNow in keysDownNow)
            if (!keysDownPrev.Contains(keyDownNow))
                OnKeyDown(new KeyEventArgs(keyDownNow));

        foreach (Evbpc.Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys keyDownPrev in keysDownPrev)
            if (!keysDownNow.Contains(keyDownPrev))
                OnKeyUp(new KeyEventArgs(keyDownPrev));

        foreach (Evbpc.Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys pressedKey in keysPressed)
            OnKeyPress(new KeyPressEventArgs(GetKeyChar(pressedKey)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <code>char</code> value represented by the <see cref="Evbpc.Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys"/> that was sent.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The <see cref="Evbpc.Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys"/> enumeration value to examine.</param>
    /// <returns>A <code>char</code> that represents the ASCII value of the key.</returns>
    public static char GetKeyChar(Evbpc.Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys key)
    {
        if ((key & Evbpc.Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift) == Evbpc.Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift)
        {
            key = key ^ Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift;

            if ((int)key >= 0x41 && (int)key <= 0x5A)
                return (char)key;

            // We made this a massive `switch` statement for the speed it provides.
            switch (key)
            {
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.D1:
                    return '!';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.D2:
                    return '@';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.D3:
                    return '#';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.D4:
                    return '$';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.D5:
                    return '%';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.D6:
                    return '^';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.D7:
                    return '&';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.D8:
                    return '*';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.D9:
                    return '(';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.D0:
                    return ')';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.OemPeriod:
                    return '>';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Oemcomma:
                    return '<';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.OemQuestion:
                    return '?';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.OemOpenBrackets:
                    return '{';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.OemCloseBrackets:
                    return '}';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.OemSemicolon:
                    return ':';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.OemQuotes:
                    return '"';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Oemtilde:
                    return '~';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Oemplus:
                    return '+';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Separator:
                    return '_';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.OemPipe:
                    return '|';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Divide:
                    return '/';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Multiply:
                    return '*';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Subtract:
                    return '-';
                case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Add:
                    return '+';
            }

            return (char)key;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((int)key >= 0x41 && (int)key <= 0x5A)
                return (char)((int)key + 32);
            else if ((int)key >= 0x30 && (int)key <= 0x39)
                return (char)key;
            else
            {
                switch (key)
                {
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Separator:
                        return '-';
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Oemplus:
                        return '=';
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Divide:
                        return '/';
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Multiply:
                        return '*';
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Subtract:
                        return '-';
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Add:
                        return '+';
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad0:
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad1:
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad2:
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad3:
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad4:
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad5:
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad6:
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad7:
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad8:
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad9:
                        return key.ToString().Substring(6, 1)[0];
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.OemPeriod:
                        return '.';
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Oemcomma:
                        return ',';
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.OemQuestion:
                        return '/';
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.OemPipe:
                        return '\\';
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.OemOpenBrackets:
                        return '[';
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.OemCloseBrackets:
                        return ']';
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.OemSemicolon:
                        return ';';
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.OemQuotes:
                        return '\'';
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Oemtilde:
                        return '`';
                    case Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Decimal:
                        return '.';
                    default:
                        return (char)key;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static Dictionary<Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys, DateTime> keysPressedAt = new Dictionary<Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys, DateTime>();
    private static Dictionary<Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys, DateTime> keyLastTickAt = new Dictionary<Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys, DateTime>();

    private List<Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys> GetPressedKeys(KeyboardState k)
    {
        List<Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys> pressedKeys = new List<Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys>();

        foreach (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys key in k.GetPressedKeys())
        {
            pressedKeys.Add(XnaKeyToKey(key));

            if (!keysPressedAt.ContainsKey(XnaKeyToKey(key)))
                keysPressedAt.Add(XnaKeyToKey(key), DateTime.Now);
        }

        return pressedKeys;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the <see cref="KeyDown"/> event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">A <see cref="KeyEventArgs"/> that contains the event data.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeydown(v=vs.110).aspx
    /// </remarks>
    protected virtual void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) { if (KeyDown != null) { KeyDown(this, e); } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the <see cref="KeyPress"/> event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">A <see cref="KeyPressEventArgs"/> that contains the event data.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeypress(v=vs.110).aspx
    /// </remarks>
    protected virtual void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e) { if (KeyPress != null) { KeyPress(this, e); } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the <see cref="KeyUp"/> event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">A <see cref="KeyEventArgs"/> that contains the event data.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeyup(v=vs.110).aspx
    /// </remarks>
    protected virtual void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e) { if (KeyUp != null) { KeyUp(this, e); } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a key is pressed while the control has focus.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx
    /// </remarks>
    public event KeyEventHandler KeyDown;
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a character. space or backspace key is pressed while the control has focus.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx
    /// </remarks>
    public event KeyPressEventHandler KeyPress;
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a key is released while the control has focus.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx
    /// </remarks>
    public event KeyEventHandler KeyUp;

    private List<Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys> GetPressedKeys()
    {
        List<Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys> pressedKeys = GetPressedKeys(_kNow);
        List<Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys> prevPressedKeys = GetPressedKeys(_kPrev);

        List<Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys> result = new List<Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys>();
        bool shiftPressed = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < pressedKeys.Count; i++)
        {
            if ((pressedKeys[i] & Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift) == Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift)
                shiftPressed = true;
            else
            {
                if (IsKeyUp(prevPressedKeys, pressedKeys[i]))
                {
                    result.Add(pressedKeys[i]);

                    if (keysPressedAt.ContainsKey(pressedKeys[i]))
                        keysPressedAt.Remove(pressedKeys[i]);

                    if (keyLastTickAt.ContainsKey(pressedKeys[i]))
                        keyLastTickAt.Remove(pressedKeys[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (keysPressedAt.ContainsKey(pressedKeys[i]))
                    {
                        TimeSpan timeDifference = DateTime.Now - keysPressedAt[pressedKeys[i]];

                        if (timeDifference > new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 250) && (keyLastTickAt.ContainsKey(pressedKeys[i]) && DateTime.Now - keyLastTickAt[pressedKeys[i]] > new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 35) || !keyLastTickAt.ContainsKey(pressedKeys[i])))
                        {
                            result.Add(pressedKeys[i]);

                            if (keyLastTickAt.ContainsKey(pressedKeys[i]))
                                keyLastTickAt[pressedKeys[i]] = DateTime.Now;
                            else
                                keyLastTickAt.Add(pressedKeys[i], DateTime.Now);
                            //keysHeld[pressedKeys[i]] = DateTime.Now;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!keysPressedAt.ContainsKey(pressedKeys[i]))
                    keysPressedAt.Add(pressedKeys[i], DateTime.Now);
            }
        }

        if (shiftPressed)
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
                result[i] = result[i] | Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift;

        return result;
    }

    private static bool IsKeyDown(List<Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys> pressedKeys, Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys key)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pressedKeys.Count; i++)
            if (pressedKeys[i] == key)
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    private static bool IsKeyUp(List<Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys> pressedKeys, Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys key)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pressedKeys.Count; i++)
            if (pressedKeys[i] == key)
                return false;

        return true;
    }

    private static Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys XnaKeyToKey(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys key)
    {
        Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys kv = Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.None;

        switch (key)
        {
            case Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.OemComma:
                kv = Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Oemcomma;
                break;
            case Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.OemTilde:
                kv = Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Oemtilde;
                break;
            case Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.OemPlus:
                kv = Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Oemplus;
                break;
            default:
                if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys), key.ToString()) | key.ToString().Contains(","))
                    kv = kv | (Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys), key.ToString());
                break;
        }

        //if ((key & Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.LeftShift) == Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.LeftShift)
        //{
        //    //kv = kv | Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.LShiftKey;
        //    kv = kv | Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift;
        //}
        //if ((key & Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.RightShift) == Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.RightShift)
        //{
        //    //kv = kv | Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.RShiftKey;
        //    kv = kv | Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift;
        //}
        //if ((key & Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.RightShift) == Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.RightShift)
        if (key == Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.LeftShift)
            kv = Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.LShiftKey | Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift;
        if (key == Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.RightShift)
            kv = Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.RShiftKey | Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift;

        return kv;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Use `foreach` when you don't need indexes

In the main loop in `GetPressedKeys`,
it seems to me you don't need the index variable `i`,
and instead of this:

> ```
>     for (int i = 0; i < pressedKeys.Count; i++)
>     {
> ```

You could rewrite the loop using `foreach`:

```
    foreach (Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys keys in pressedKeys)
    {
```

You can do likewise in `IsKeyDown` and `IsKeyUp` too.

#### Avoid duplicated logic

The implementations of `IsKeyDown` and `IsKeyUp` look very very similar.
You could avoid duplicating logic by generalizing:

```
private static bool IsPressedState(List<Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys> pressedKeys, Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys key, bool state)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pressedKeys.Count; i++)
        if (pressedKeys[i] == key)
            return state;

    return !state;
}

private static bool IsKeyDown(List<Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys> pressedKeys, Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys key)
{
    return IsPressedState(pressedKeys, key, true);
}

private static bool IsKeyUp(List<Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys> pressedKeys, Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys key)
{
    return IsPressedState(pressedKeys, key, false);
}
```

#### Avoid too similar variable names

While it's admirable that you used perfectly self-descriptive variable names here,
it's really easy to get lost in the references to `keyDownNow`, `keysDownNow`, `keyDownPrev`, `keysDownPrev`:

> ```
>     foreach (Evbpc.Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys keyDownNow in keysDownNow)
>         if (!keysDownPrev.Contains(keyDownNow))
>             OnKeyDown(new KeyEventArgs(keyDownNow));
>
>     foreach (Evbpc.Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys keyDownPrev in keysDownPrev)
>         if (!keysDownNow.Contains(keyDownPrev))
>             OnKeyUp(new KeyEventArgs(keyDownPrev));
> ```

I suggest to simplify the loop variables (the singular names, `keyDownNow` and `keyDownPrev`) to simply `key`.

#### Simplify to `^=` and `|=`

Instead of this:

> ```
> key = key ^ Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift;
> ```

I believe you can write more compactly as:

```
key ^= Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift;
```

Likewise, instead of this:

> ```
> result[i] = result[i] | Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift;
> ```

You could write:

```
result[i] |= Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift;
```

#### Reduce nesting

When a brach in a conditional returns,
you can reduce nesting by removing `else if` and `else` statements.
For example instead of this:

> ```
>         if ((int)key >= 0x41 && (int)key <= 0x5A)
>             return (char)((int)key + 32);
>         else if ((int)key >= 0x30 && (int)key <= 0x39)
>             return (char)key;
>         else
>         {
>             switch (key)
>             {
>                 // ...
>             }
> ```

You can write like this, especially notice the reduced indentation of the `switch`:

```
        if ((int)key >= 0x41 && (int)key <= 0x5A)
            return (char)((int)key + 32);
        if ((int)key >= 0x30 && (int)key <= 0x39)
            return (char)key;

        switch (key)
        {
            // ...
        }
```

Comment: Rather than creating `IsPressedState()` with a confusing `bool`, use LINQ:  `IsKeyDown(..) { return pressedKeys.Any(o => o == key); }` `IsKeyUp(..) { return !IsKeyDown(key); }`. Also rather than the magic numbers `0x30` `0x39` `0x41` `0x5A`, use the `char`-values they're meant to represent: `'0'` `'9'` `'A'` `'Z'`

Answer (score 5):

Personally I don't like this

> ```
>     foreach (Evbpc.Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys keyDownNow in keysDownNow)
>         if (!keysDownPrev.Contains(keyDownNow))
>             OnKeyDown(new KeyEventArgs(keyDownNow));
>
>     foreach (Evbpc.Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys keyDownPrev in keysDownPrev)
>         if (!keysDownNow.Contains(keyDownPrev))
>             OnKeyUp(new KeyEventArgs(keyDownPrev));
> ```

Braceless if statements inside braceless foreach statements.  They just don't look C#-ish enough for me

And then you go and do this

> ```
>         if ((pressedKeys[i] & Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift) == Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift)
>             shiftPressed = true;
>         else
>         {
> ```

that is ugly, you should never do this.

---

looks like you figured this out as well

> ```
>     //if ((key & Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.LeftShift) == Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.LeftShift)
>     //{
>     //    //kv = kv | Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.LShiftKey;
>     //    kv = kv | Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift;
>     //}
>     //if ((key & Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.RightShift) == Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.RightShift)
>     //{
>     //    //kv = kv | Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.RShiftKey;
>     //    kv = kv | Framework.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift;
>     //}
>     //if ((key & Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.RightShift) == Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.RightShift)
> ```

don't let it clutter your code. as soon as you know your new stuff works, trash the commented code.

Answer (score 4):

Some points I noticed myself:

- Magic numbers for `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 250)` and `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 35)`, make them Properties and/or Fields.
- I should use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now` for internal timings. (I remembered this from [this answer on another question of mine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/100720/73844).)
- Use `var` for certain variables. Though, generally, I am against it, it definitely helps take care of keeping things clean here.